# Creating an array with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using mysqli to query an item database. I am trying to create an array out of the items in the database, but am stuck. Here is what I have so far.

```
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';
$DB_NAME = 'test';

$connection = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if ($query = $connection->prepare('SELECT name, due_date, complete FROM items WHERE user_id = ?')) {
    $query->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
    $query->execute(); 
    $query->store_result();
    //var_dump($query->num_rows);
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        $query->bind_result($name, $due_date, $complete);
        //$query->fetch();

        while ($query->fetch()) {

       }
    }
    $query->close();

}
```

I am completely unsure how to turn this into an array for use in a foreach loop in my list of items.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `mysqlnd`, just use `->get_result()` after `execute()`.

```
$query = $connection->prepare('SELECT name, due_date, complete FROM items WHERE user_id = ?');
$query->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // fetch as associative

// then make your foreach or whatnot
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // echo $row['name'];
}
```

If you don't want them all loaded up immediately, you can still use the `while` + `fetch` combo:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // echo $row['name']
    // $data[] = $row;
    // or whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: @TheDizzle sure glad this helped